# Execute python code on uploaded files

Tags: python, html, django

I have a django application where I upload 2 files and want to run a python script on them (proto2.py).

In my html code I added a button to execute a file but it didn't work :

```
<div>Relay 1:
    <form action="{% url "nettoyage"%}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Toggle" id="toggle1" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

urls.py :

```
url(r'^nettoyage/$', 'nettoyage',name='nettoyage'),
```

views.py :

```
def nettoyage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import proto2
    return #Something, normally a HTTPResponse, using django
```

proto2.py :

```
file = xlrd.open_workbook('~/Paye_P5_test.xlsx',encoding_override='utf-8')

sheet = file.sheet_by_name('Feuil1')
headers = [str(cell.value) for cell in sheet.row(0)] 

values = []
for rowind in range(sheet.nrows)[1:]:
    values.append([ cell.value for cell in sheet.row(rowind)])

data2=pandas.DataFrame(data=values,columns=headers)
resume=data2['Résumé']
resume = resume.str.lower()
resume = resume.str.replace("'", " ")

remov_punct = str.maketrans({key: None for key in string.punctuation})
resume = resume.str.translate(remov_punct)

resume = html.unescape(resume)

stop_words = get_stop_words('french')
resume = resume.str.split()
resume = resume.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in stop_words])

# Porter Stemmer Algo
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("french")
resume = resume.apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(item) for item in x])
resume[0]
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py` file.

Comment: What's the URL generated by `{% url "nettoyage"%}`?

Comment: This one : url(r'^nettoyage/$', 'nettoyage',name='nettoyage'),

Comment: I mean, what's generated inside your html template?

Comment: I don't know...?
Maybe if you see my .html it will help you ?

Comment: I think we should transfer to a chat to get this done, since you don't have enough rep we can't use SO's chat. Meet me there : https://us23.chatzy.com/42307926567619 :)

Comment: http://www.chatzy.com/42307926567619 if it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies here :

```
<form action="{% url "nettoyage"%}" method="POST">
```

Change it by :

```
<form action="{% url 'nettoyage'%}" method="POST">
```

The doubles quotes interfere with the `action` attribute, therefore closing it and leaving a quote open. Changing it by a simple `'` quote will resolve your issue.

Comment: Perfect. It works perfectly. And we corrected it quickly :)

Just : Thank you !